# expected rbrace at line 4 col 14 font-size not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to edit the community header on my Wikia by using the custom css
Here's my code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
.wds-community-header__sitename {
    font-family: "Press Start 2P"
    font-size: small;
}
```

And, it's not working!
It comes up with this.

> expected rbrace at line 4 col 14

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

It says it's expecting a right brace (`}`), but I'm not seeing any missing braces. You have a missing semicolon (`;`) at the end of line 3, which seems to have something to do with the message.